# All pairwise means between elements of 2 lists

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a function to **all** pairwise means (or sums, etc) of 2 lists in python?

I can write a nested loop to do this:

```
import numpy as np

A = [1,2,3]
B = [8,12,11]

C = np.empty((len(A),len(B)))
for i, x in enumerate(A):
    for j, y in enumerate(B):
        C[i][j] = np.mean([x,y])
```

result:

```
array([[4.5, 6.5, 6. ],
       [5. , 7. , 6.5],
       [5.5, 7.5, 7. ]])
```

but it feels like this is a very roundabout way to do this.
I guess there is an option for a nested list comprehension as well, but that also seems ugly.

Is there a more pythonic solution?

Comment: Just do: `np.add(*np.meshgrid(B, A))/2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [8, 12, 11]
C = np.add.outer(A, B) / 2
# array([[4.5, 6.5, 6. ],
#        [5. , 7. , 6.5],
#        [5.5, 7.5, 7. ]])
```

Comment: It's very nice.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using `numpy`? If so, you can broadcast your arrays and acheive this in one line.

```
import numpy as np

A = [1,2,3]
B = [8,12,11]

C = (np.reshape(A, (-1, 1)) + B) / 2 # Here B will be implicitly converted to a numpy array. Thanks to @Jérôme Richard.
```

Comment: Well, the output for your code is: `[[4.5 6.5 6. ]
 [5.  7.  6.5]
 [5.5 7.5 7. ]]`. This comes when I print `C`.

Comment: If you print `type(C)`, you will find it is a numpy array. :)

Comment: Yeah, but could you convert that into a list for the required output `[4.5, 7.0, 7.0]`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this. But I don't think the type of the result is very important for this question. the asker wants neat and pythonic solutions. :) I will edit it if the asker clarifies his intention.

Comment: I don't really care about the type, and indeed I want the nested list with all pairwise averages, not just the averages of the corresponding elements.

Comment: Is there any reason to use reshape rather than meshgrid, as pointed out by @Jérôme Richard? The meshgrid looks slightly neater to me, but not a big difference

Comment: In this case, when you use `meshgrid` you really produce two 3x3 arrays. For `reshape`, you don't touch the underlying storage of arrays. @db_

Comment: I also think it's slightly more intuitive to understand what's going using reshape than meshgrid. I needed to convert this to a geometric mean solution as well, and needed a tiny bit less thinking to understand how to do it for reshape than for meshgrid :)

Comment: @TheMyth, that is not the output I am looking for. I want the same output as the one in my original post. I was just looking for a neater way to code it.

Answer (score 1):

What I feel is you could use only one for loop to make things pretty clean. By using the `zip()` function you could make the code easier. One of the best approaches with the least time complexity `O(logn)` would be:

```
import numpy as np
A = [1,2,3]
B = [8,12,11]
C = [np.mean([x,y]) for x,y in zip(A,B)] # List Comprehension to decrease lines
print(C)
```

Comment: this gives a 1D list of averages, same as `np.mean([A,B],axis=0)` would do

Comment: Well, it's another `pythonic approach`. with the lowest possible time complexity. I don't find it incorrect.

Comment: it gives a different result than I was asking for. Your code results in [4.5, 7.0, 7.0], so the averages of the corresponding list elements. 
The result I want is average between each element of the first list with each element of the second list, i.e.: 
[[4.5 6.5 6. ]
 [5.  7.  6.5]
 [5.5 7.5 7. ]].
(Your result is the diagonal of the one I'm looking for)

Answer (score 1):

I propose a list comprehension like this:

```
C= [[(xx+yy)/2 for yy in B] for xx in A]
```

Comment: This is exactly something that they have done, but in `list comprehension`.

Comment: nested list comprehension not quite as ugly as I suspected (and definitely much better than nested loops from my original post) :P